# How can i hide an selector when the value of another selector is chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide a selector , when the value of the other selector is selected

I have already tried the following code but it doesnt work

My jquery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#Soort').val() == "Bordspellen") {
        $('#Categorie_computer').hide();
        $('#4').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="2">Wat speelt u meestal?</label>
<select id="Soort" name="Soort">
    <option value="">Kies...</option>
    <option value="bordspel">Bordspellen</option>
    <option value="computer">Computergame's</option>
</select>

<br>

<label id="4">Welke Categorie Computergame speelt u meestal?</label>
<select id="Categorie_computer" name="Categorie_computer">
    <option value="">Kies...</option>
    <option value="Sport">Sport games</option>
    <option value="Adventure">Adventure games</option>
    <option value="War">War games</option>
    <option value="Stategisch_computer">Strategische games</option>
</select>
```

i want that if in the selector with label id 2 "Bordspellen" is chosen
the selector with label id 4 hides

Comment: Your ids should contain at least one character, not only numbers

Answer (score 2):

Add `change` event to your first `select` tag and check for option value selected. If it is `bordspel` then hide the other selector.

```js
$('#Soort').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'bordspel') {
    $('#4, #Categorie_computer').hide();
  } else {
    $('#4, #Categorie_computer').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="2">Wat speelt u meestal?</label>
<select id="Soort" name="Soort">
  <option value="">Kies...</option>
  <option value="bordspel">Bordspellen</option>
  <option value="computer">Computergame's</option>
</select>

<label id="4">Welke Categorie Computergame speelt u meestal?</label>
<select id="Categorie_computer" name="Categorie_computer">
  <option value="">Kies...</option>
  <option value="Sport">Sport games</option>
  <option value="Adventure">Adventure games</option>
  <option value="War">War games</option>
  <option value="Stategisch_computer">Strategische games</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

1) You compare the value of the select element with 'Bordspellen' but the value you've assigned to that option is 'bordspel'. This comparison will never be true. You should check if the value of '#Soort' is equal to 'bordspel'.

2) You check the initial value when the document is loaded but this way you will not be informed when a different selection is made. For this to happen you need to listen to the change event.

I've updated your code to address both issues. I hope this makes it clear.

```js
$('#Soort').change(function() {
    if ($('#Soort').val() == "bordspel") {
        $('#Categorie_computer').hide();
        $('#4').hide();
    } else {
        $('#Categorie_computer').show();
        $('#4').show();    
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="2">Wat speelt u meestal?</label>
<select id="Soort" name="Soort">
    <option value="">Kies...</option>
    <option value="bordspel">Bordspellen</option>
    <option value="computer">Computergame's</option>
</select>
<label id="4">Welke Categorie Computergame speelt u meestal?</label>
<select id="Categorie_computer" name="Categorie_computer">
    <option value="">Kies...</option>
    <option value="Sport">Sport games</option>
    <option value="Adventure">Adventure games</option>
    <option value="War">War games</option>
    <option value="Stategisch_computer">Strategische games</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap a div as a container-element around each select and its label. So you can hide all contents of that container easily. Also you must observe the change-event of the select. When that event is triggered you can compare the value or text of the selection. The Value is the actual value that is hidden and can be submitted to a server etc. and the text is the content rendered in the browser.

```js
$('#Soort').on('change', function(){
  if ($('#Soort').val() == "bordspel") {
    $('#container-4').hide();
  } else {
    $('#container-4').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container-2">
  <label>Wat speelt u meestal?</label>
  <select id="Soort" name="Soort">
    <option value="">Kies...</option>
    <option value="bordspel">Bordspellen</option>
    <option value="computer">Computergame's</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="container-4">
  <label>Welke Categorie Computergame speelt u meestal?</label>
  <select id="Categorie_computer" name="Categorie_computer">
    <option value="">Kies...</option>
    <option value="Sport">Sport games</option>
    <option value="Adventure">Adventure games</option>
    <option value="War">War games</option>
    <option value="Stategisch_computer">Strategische games</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the onchange event of jquery.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

$('#Soort').on('change',function(){

  var value = $(this).val();
  
  if(value ==="bordspel"){
    
    $('#4').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#Categorie_computer').remove();

}



});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="2">Wat speelt u meestal?</label>
        <select id="Soort" name="Soort">
            <option value="">Kies...</option>
            <option value="bordspel">Bordspellen</option>
            <option value="computer">Computergame's</option>
        </select>



        <label id="4">Welke Categorie Computergame speelt u meestal?</label>
        <select id="Categorie_computer" name="Categorie_computer">
            <option value="">Kies...</option>
            <option value="Sport">Sport games</option>
            <option value="Adventure">Adventure games</option>
            <option value="War">War games</option>
            <option value="Stategisch_computer">Strategische games</option>
        </select>
```